# Bash looping a file and placing lines in another file based on finding string in line

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to process a large file 4 Gig and want each line to go to a specific file but cant seem to get it. Can someone help me find out what works best for this in Ubuntu 20. I have been at this for hours but cannot seem to get it. Am I even close?

**test.log**

```
go to file 1
should go to file 2
should be seen in file 3
another for file 3 I belong in file 3
file 2 is my place
```

**processLog.sh**

```
  while read -r LINE
  do
     grep -h "file 1" > file1.txt
     grep -h "file 2" > file2.txt
     grep -h "file 3" > file3.txt
  done < test.log
```

**Expected Results**

```
file1.txt
    go to file 1
file2.txt
    should go to file 2
    file 2 is my place
file3.txt
    should be seen in file 3
    another for file 3 I belong in file 3
```

**Final Used**

@William Pursell thank you for the answer it rips thru the 4Gig file like a Lightsaber thru butter!

In the end, I used the following; to help others it's here in its entirety. Called on the bash CLI which is why the trailing backslashes are there. Notice the first line is a negation (!) so it gets all that does NOT have "INSERT INTO ". The rest of the lines look for a specific string and place it into a specific file. Happy Awking!

```
awk '\
!/INSERT INTO / {print > "DATE_mysql_om.sql"; next } \
/INSERT INTO `objecttype`/ {print > "insert_om_objecttype.sql"; next } \
/INSERT INTO `objecttag`/ {print > "insert_om_objecttag.sql"; next } \
/INSERT INTO `object_objecttag`/ {print > "insert_om_object_objecttag.sql"; next } \
/INSERT INTO `indexlogger`/ {print > "insert_om_indexlogger.sql";}' \
*_mysqldump.sql
```

Comment: how many new files do you expect to create? a dozen? 100's? 1000's? more?

Comment: could a line contain references to more than one file (eg, `file 1 and file 2`) and if so, should the line be written to all files, the 1st file, the 2nd file, the last file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` is the wrong tool for something like this.  If you want lines that match the string "file 1" to be written to `file1.txt`, etc, you could do something like:

```
awk '/file 1/ { print > "file1.txt"; next } /file 2/ {print > "file2.txt"; next }` input-file
```

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should work for you in a single action block using `match` function:

```bash
awk 'match($0, /file [0-9]+/) {
   print > (substr($0, RSTART, 4) substr($0, RSTART+5, RLENGTH-5) ".txt")
}' file
```